# How To Consolidate Multiple Rows Into One Row

Tags: excel, vba

My situation is as follows. I have a list of around 2k student accounts and sort the information to a specific format that i can format to our new CRM. The way the data is presented initially makes that problematic.

As you can see on the first screenshot, every student's university choice is presented in a separate row. So if a student has chosen more than one university, data about it is stored in 2-6 rows (each student can select 1 to 6 universities) repeating his personalID, name, forename and DoB every line.

What I need to achieve is to remove repeating information and store all data about each student in one row per student(example on screenshot 2).

I have no idea how to achieve this using VBA. I was trying with IFs, loops and arrays but without any progress. I need help on how to accomplish that using VBA.

Please let me know if you need more information. I will try to explain it in more details if required.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrM7o.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIVCn.png)

EDIT: This is the part of the report. I am working on a macro that will format it to our needs and will give us more info about the student's accounts. That is why I am asking for help in VBA.

Comment: I will need to run the macro every week on the data that will be in the same format as on the first screenshot.

Comment: When you have such repeating data, and want to turn rows into columns, the data operation is called *pivoting* - a pivot table can do this, but assuming the data source isn't already on SQL Server (in which case you'd just pivot it at the source, in T-SQL) you'll want to use PowerQuery to pivot the data if you don't want a pivot table. Using VBA for this would be reinventing the wheel =)

Comment: Welcome to SO @KacperMuryn - Try to produce a [small, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Doing this will make the crux of the problem more clear...and usually help you resolve the question yourself, but if it does not, it makes it far easier for others to provide you a usable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work. I'm new to VBA and programming in general so it's possibly not the most efficient solution and can definitely be improved.
Instead of working with a blank sheet, it transforms the current data to the format you wanted.  You can add field headings where you want.

Edit: It assumes that each Student has 5 universities in the list. The code can be adjusted to account for any number by just adjusting the target range dynamically.

Edit 2: I added the change to account for students who've entered any number of universities between 1 to 5. Let me know if this gets it done!

```
Sub ReArrange_Data()

Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim First As Integer
Dim Last As Integer
Dim test As Integer
Dim test1 As Integer
Dim student_range As Range
Dim student_rows As Integer
Dim target_range As Range
First = 2

For i = 2 To lrow
    Last = First
    If Cells(First, "D").Value = "" Then GoTo Break    'reached end of data

    While Cells(Last, "D").Value = Cells(Last + 1, "D").Value
       Last = Last + 1
    Wend
    If Last <> First Then             'check if mulitiple uni and build range
        Set student_range = Range("E" & First & ":" & "E" & Last)
        student_rows = student_range.Rows.Count
        If student_rows = 5 Then
            Set target_range = Range("E" & First & ":" & "I" & First)
        ElseIf student_rows = 4 Then
            Set target_range = Range("E" & First & ":" & "H" & First)
        ElseIf student_rows = 3 Then
            Set target_range = Range("E" & First & ":" & "G" & First)
        ElseIf student_rows = 2 Then
            Set target_range = Range("E" & First & ":" & "F" & First)
        End If

    Else
        GoTo Skip        'student entered one uni, go to next loop
    End If


    target_range = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(student_range.Value)   'row to column
    Rows(First + 1 & ":" & Last).EntireRow.Delete
Skip:                                             'delete repeated entries
    First = First + 1

Next i
Break:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for! Your code is helpful and works almost perfect. The only this is, that when a student has chosen only one university it goes crazy and skip that person + next students' choices are mismatched.

Comment: @KacperMuryn Good to hear! I made the changes and it should work for students entering 1 to 5 universities.

Comment: Huge thanks! This code is great! It works perfectly and does everything that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use VBA for this. Power Query will help you better. Have a look here: https://excelgorilla.com/power-bi/power-query/aggregate-text-values-using-group-by/